# How do I keep gnome-terminal width from changing when I use "reset"

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

When I use `reset` in gnome-terminal (bash, Ubuntu 9.04), the window width resets, though the height does not. On my personal computer, this does not happen in xterm or konsole. On my work computer (RHEL 5 or maybe 4), this does not happen in any terminals, including gnome-terminal. I assume there is some environment variable that controls this, but my .bashrc at work is hundreds of lines long, so I'm not sure where to look in there.

Comment: What is `TERM` set to?

Comment: xterm, on my home machine; will check at work later

Comment: xterm on my work machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

To check your current terminal size settings use:

```
stty size
```

You'll get something like this:

```
$ stty size
70 196
```

If your width is smaller than it should be, then you can change your terminals height and width with this command:

```
stty rows 70 cols 200; reset
```

or just width:

```
stty cols 200; reset
```

Where 200 is the new width.

But resizing your gnome-terminal will most like change cols setting again. And this does not solve the underlying problem.

Also I could not reproduce this problem with gnome-terminal 3.0.1-0ubuntu3 from ubuntu oneiric.